# Draw vertical lines in jqplot chart which x axe has Date format

Tags: charts, jqplot

I have a jqPlot chart with X axe has the following format:

```
xaxis: {
             renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
             tickOptions: {
                          formatString: '%Y-%m-%d \n %H:%M'
                          },
             min: minimo,
             max: maximo,
       }
```

I am not able to draw vertical lines in my chart with the plugin $.jqplot.CanvasOverlay.VerticalLine, like it is shown in this example:
[example canvas-overlay jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/canvas-overlay.html#)
I've tried the example on its own and works but in my case, since my chart has a format in the x axe I was only able to make it work with horizontal lines, but not with vertical lines.

This is what I have tried for now:

```
verticalLine: {
                    name: 'barney',
                    x: "2011-01-07 16:10:00.000",
                    lineWidth: 6,
                    color: 'rgb(100, 55, 124)',
                    shadow: false
                }
```

I also assigned the x value to a variable and `x: "2011-01-07 \n 16:10:00.000"` but still didn't work.
Maybe I just should do it drawing another jqPlot chart on top of the one I already have. But I would like to avoid that solution if possible and prefer the VerticalLine approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jqplot is expecting a numerical value and not a string (even for date) and can't convert the value you pass from string to a date.

You can jsDate object in jqplot to convert your date string to a numerical value :

```
x : new $.jsDate( '2011-01-07 16:10:00.000').getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also wanted more than just one vertical line. So I had to create a list of objects for the VerticalLines.

```
var dates_vertical=[/*Array wit Dates*/];
var objects_vertical=[];
function create_vertical_lines() {
  for (var j = 0; j < dates_vertical.length ; j++) {
   objects_vertical[j]= new Object({ "verticalLine": {     
   "x": new $.jsDate(dates_vertical[j]).getTime(),
   "color": "red", 
   "lineWidth": 4 
   } 
 });
};
```

Besides in my CanvasOverlay I wrote:

```
canvasOverlay: {
          show: true,
          objects: objects_vertical
      }
```

Thanks!!